# backbone click event fires as many times as there is views

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, click

I searched info on this topic but found only info about getting event element.
Yes, I can get an element of clicked div, but why it's fired all 19 times? (it's the number of views total). Info of clicked event is same - of the clicked div.

Here is what divs look like: http://d.pr/i/AbJP

Here is console.log: http://d.pr/i/zncs

Here is the code of index.js

```
$(function () {
var Table = new Backbone.Collection;
var TrModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: '0',
        name: 'defaultName'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.view = new Tr({model: this, collection: Table});
        this.on('destroy', function () {
            this.view.remove();
        })
    }
});
var Tr = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.pop-tags').find('.container'),
    template: _.template($('#td_template').html()),
    events: {
        'click .tag': 'clicked'
    },
    clicked: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});
for (var i = 0, size = 19; i < size; i++) {
    var trModel = new TrModel({id: i, name: 'name_' + i});
    Table.add(trModel);
}
```

});

How can I avoid all elements from firing an event and fire only one that clicked and only 1 time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
el: $('.pop-tags').find('.container'),
```

Don't do that. You are attaching every view instance to the same DOM node. Each backbone view needs a distinct DOM node or, as you see, delegate events become complete chaos. In your view, set `tagName: 'tr'`, then when creating your views, create them, call `.render()` and then append them to the DOM with something like `$('.table-where-views-go').append(trView.el);`.

You also may want to brush up on the basic MVC concept because Tables and Rows are view-related notions, not model-related, so a class called `TrModel` is a code smell that you aren't clear on Model vs View.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a slightly different approach to solve your problem.

Instead for one view for every tr I would create one view for the entire table.

When I create the view I would pass the collection containing the 19 models to the view and in view.initialize use the collection to render the rows.

I created a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/IQoDAHu/2/edit?js,console,output) with a working example.

Comment: Would I be able to transfer my models from one collection to another with this approach? Also I though about that, that my approach is not 'right'. I have system with all tags and tags pool to sort rows by them, so I though it will be easy to 'play' with 'one model - one view - transfer them between collections of all tags and tags pool'.

Thank you for your answer!